# phpMyAdmin attribute constraint

Tags: phpmyadmin, constraints

I have a table 'date' with an attributes months and I would like to give a constraints to it in order for the value to always be under 13.

BTW, I'm using the interface of phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to handle this; you could do a trigger, stored procedure, make the column an `enum`, or use the phpMyAdmin "input transformation" feature. Of those, personally I would definitely go with a trigger, though only you can know your needs and requirements.

This works for me:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `force_month` BEFORE INSERT ON `insert_trigger`
  FOR EACH ROW IF (new.`month` NOT BETWEEN 1 and 12) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Not a valid month';
  END IF
```